# how to test stop start of AWS Spot Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am creating AWS spot instances on demand and wanted to keep interruption behavior as STOP, so that AWS can restart my VM as soon as price/demand meets.

But the problem is AWS GUI doesn't have any option to STOP running spot instances.
It just have option to terminate instances or cancel spot requests.

I am developing some application which will resume itself on reboot.
I wanted to test the application by simulating AWS stop and restart behaviour.

Thx in advance

~Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now you cannot Stop a Spot Instance.

To simulate your application behavior, bid for minimum and wait for AWS to interrupt the instance.
Make sure that your spot instance is Stop Interruption ready.

Reference:
[Spot Instance Interruptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an option to restart a SPOT instance. SPOT instance is not the right candidate for this kind of application.